# How do you stop MSBuild execution without raising an error?

Tags: msbuild

With MSBuild, as soon as an error occurs, the execution of the project is stopped unless `ContinueOnError=true`.

Is there a way to stop the execution of the project without raising an error?

I'd like to have this possibility because I have an existing set of msbuild project files and in some circumstances, I would need to stop processing the projects without raising an error because it is a normal exit point for the process and I don't want the person using the script to think something is wrong.

I know I could just set some property and put all remaining tasks conditional on this but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: What do you mean "*normal exit point*". If the targets are not completed which were targeted then how can this be normal? Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish so that we can understand what exactly you need?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you explain it, you want to stop your build under special circumstance without raising an error because it is a normal exit point. Why not create a target doing nothing that will serve as your exit point. Under your special conditions you will call this target.

```
<target Name="BuildProcess">
   <Message Text="Build starts"/>
   ...
   <CallTarget Targets="Exit"
               Condition="Special Condition"/>

   <CallTarget Targets="Continue"
               Condition="!(Special Condition)"/> 
   ...     
</target>

<target Name="Continue">
  <Message Text="Build continue"/>  
</target>

<target Name="Exit">
  <!-- This target could be removed -->
  <!-- Only used for logging here -->
  <Message Text="Build ended because special condition occured"/>
</target>
```

Comment: This is really slick but doesn't work for me using msbuild 4.0. The execution returns to the target that used CallTarget and continues (so "Build continue" gets printed on the screen as well). Are there any workarounds you could suggest?

Comment: Thanks. But now there's no need for the Exit target. If the special condition is not met, we jump to the Continue target, otherwise we stay in BuildProcess (which should just end there).

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is the create another target to wrap the target you're interested in conditioning.

So if you have a scenario with a target like this:

```
<Target Name="MainTarget">
command - run under a certain condition
command - run under a certain condition
command - run under a certain condition
command - run under a certain condition
command - run under a certain condition
</Target>
```

The point is that you want to save having to use the condition statement a whole bunch of times, right?

To address this, you can do this:

```
<Target Name="MainWrapper" DependsOnTargets="EstablishCondition;MainTarget" />

<Target Name="EstablishCondition">
<SomeCustomTask Input="blah">
 <Output PropertyName="TestProperty" TaskParameter="value" />
</SomeCustomTask>
</Target>

<Target Name="MainTarget" Condition="$(TestProperty)='true'">

command
command
command
command
command

</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eventually found an elegant solution for a similar issue. I just needed to rephrase my concern from "*Break/interrupt MSBuild execution*" to "*Skip the next targets*".

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <LastInfoFileName>LastInfo.xml</LastInfoFileName>
 <NewInfoFileName>NewInfo.xml</NewInfoFileName>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="CheckSomethingFirst" BeforeTargets="DoSomething">

 <Message Condition="ConditionForContinue"
          Text="Let's carry on with next target" />
 <WriteLinesToFile Condition="ConditionForContinue" 
                   File="$(NewInfoFileName)"
                   Lines="@(SomeText)"
                   Overwrite="true" />

 <Message Condition="!ConditionForContinue"
          Text="Let's discard next target" />
 <Copy Condition="!ConditionForContinue"
       SourceFiles="$(LastInfoFileName)"
       DestinationFiles="$(NewInfoFileName)" />

</Target>

<Target Name="DoSomething" Inputs="$(NewInfoFileName)"
                           Outputs="$(LastInfoFileName)">
 <Message Text="DoSomethingMore" />
 <Copy SourceFiles="$(NewInfoFileName)"
       DestinationFiles="$(LastInfoFileName)" />
</Target>
```

This works ok with a command like:

```
msbuild.exe Do.targets /t:DoSomething
```

where target **DoSomething** Inputs/Outputs are correctly checked after the **CheckSomethingFirst** target was executed.