# Exiting a MSBuild target on a certain conditions with success

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I am trying to exit a target on a certain condition.

I am using

```
Error Code="0" Condition="'$(SOMETHING)' == '1'"/>
```

this causes my build from TFS to fail.

Is there a way to exit a MSBuild target with success?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you stop MSBuild execution without raising an error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284389/how-do-you-stop-msbuild-execution-without-raising-an-error)

Answer (score 3):

If you want exit a target success on a certain condition but with error

Try this:

```
<Error Code="0" Condition="$(SOMETHING) == '1'"/>
```

If you want exit a MSbuild target success  which mean without raising an error, please reference the answer from *Julien Hoarau*  [How do you stop MSBuild execution without raising an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284389/how-do-you-stop-msbuild-execution-without-raising-an-error)