# Why is my web job running in DEBUG mode on the server

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs

I created a web job that runs on an Azure web app server. I am also using Devops to deploy the web job to the server. The deploy itself works, and the webjob (continuous) shows up on the server. However, when I check the logs, I see that it is logging some information that is within `@if DEBUG` tags. This is my first time using Devops with a web job. Is there something I could be doing wrong in the build/release process? Below is my yaml code for the build pipeline:

```
# ASP.NET

# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/RingClone.Starter.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: 'Starter.RingCentral.IndexPriority.Voice/Starter.RingCentral.IndexPriority.Voice.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration Release'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: 'Starter.RingCentral.IndexPriority.Voice/Starter.RingCentral.IndexPriority.Voice.csproj'
    arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/continuous/Starter.RingCentral.IndexPriority.Voice'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false


- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Is there anything in here that could be causing the web job to be running in DEBUG mode?

Also, as requested, here is the contents of the main csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk;Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CsvHelper" Version="27.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.123" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.12.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos" Version="3.9.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="3.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Web.Deployment" Version="4.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Caching" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.4.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.4.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.4.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.4.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ConvosoActions\ConvosoActions.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\FtpActions\FtpActions.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\GlobalEntities\GlobalEntities.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\InContactActions\InContactActions.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\RingCentralOfficeHandActions\RingCentralOfficeHandActions.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\RingCentral\RingCentralActions.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\RingCloneCore\RingCloneCore.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Caching">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.1\System.Runtime.Caching.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="Settings.job">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Show us your `.csproj` files.

Comment: Sure thing @Dai, I just added the main csproj file to the question.

Comment: (Off-topic, but what's with the `<Reference Include="System.Runtime.Caching">` reference? That definitely won't work in ASP.NET Core 3.1)

Comment: I think I added that way back before I converted this to dotnet core actually.

Comment: Can you log or intercept or otherwise find out the exact `msbuild` command that ultimately gets invoked via `command: 'build'`?

Comment: I noticed your `publish` action doesn't specify `--configuration Release` - what happens if you add that?

Comment: Looks like it is running this in the first CLI task:

Comment: "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build D:\a\1\s\Starter.RingCentral.IndexPriority.Voice\Starter.RingCentral.IndexPriority.Voice.csproj "-dl:CentralLogger,\"D:\a\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.221.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll\"*ForwardingLogger,\"D:\a\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.221.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll\"" --configuration Release
MSBuild version 17.6.8+c70978d4d for .NET

Comment: I'll try the "--configuration Release" in the publish task. I am assuming that would go in the "arguments" field, correct?

Comment: Yep. I might also recommend adding a `<Target>` to your `.csproj` that aborts the build if `$(Configuration)` is not set .

Comment: If it helps, this is in the second CLI task:

Comment: Info: .NET Core SDK/runtime 2.2 and 3.0 are now End of Life(EOL) and have been removed from all hosted agents. If you're using these SDK/runtimes on hosted agents, kindly upgrade to newer versions which are not EOL, or else use UseDotNet task to install the required version.
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" publish D:\a\1\s\Starter.RingCentral.IndexPriority.Voice\Starter.RingCentral.IndexPriority.Voice.csproj --output D:\a\1\b/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/continuous/Starter.RingCentral.IndexPriority.Voice
MSBuild version 17.6.8+c70978d4d for .NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Converting my comments to an answer)

The problem here is that your `command: 'publish'` action will cause a new build (rather than re-using the `Release` output of `command: 'build'`), but because the `'publish'` action doesn't specify `--configuration Release` it will cause the MSBuild `$(Configuration)` property to default to `DEBUG`[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284389/how-do-you-stop-msbuild-execution-without-raising-an-error).

So change the `arguments` string of `'publish'` to include `--configuration Release` and you should be good-to-go.

---

I might recommend adding a new `<Target>` to your `.csproj` that will [cause MSBuild to abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284389/how-do-you-stop-msbuild-execution-without-raising-an-error) whenever `$(Configuration)` is not explicitly set, like so:

```
// Ensure this <Target> is near the top of your `.csproj` so other <Import>'s defaults won't hide this issue.
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/error-task?view=vs-2022

<Target Name="ValidateCommandLine">
    <Error Condition="'$(Configuration)' == ''" Text="Build aborted because the 'Configuration' MSBuild property is not set." />
</Target>
```

---

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284389/how-do-you-stop-msbuild-execution-without-raising-an-error): For "pre-SDK" `.csproj` files, you'll find this MSBuild property in your first `<PropertyGroup>` element:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    [...]
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    [...]
</PropertyGroup>
```

...while in "SDK-style" `.csproj` files this same `<Configuration>` property default still exists, but is located in `dotnet\sdk\$version\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.DefaultOutputPaths.targets` instead.